# HTML5 audio element do not work in the internet information service server

Tags: c#, iis, html5-audio

I have created an audio stream starting from OBS to a RTMP followed by streaming from the RTMP Server via VLC to an HTTP stream. I have created the following HTML 5 Audio side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls="controls" runat="server" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="http://innoszorn.ddnss.de:11001/stream.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Running the side in the Visual Studio 2017 envirnonment the player works. But after publishing the project to the IIS Server the player doesn't work anymore. Also with VLC you can connect to the stream.

Comment: I tried that, i created an html and put it in IIS it works. Can you tell other details behind this issue you encounter? Is it a simple html page or it is inside in a Web Application?

Comment: It's inside a Web Application. If I just start the html page it works. It looks like there is an issue with the IIS Server. What I don't understand is, why it works on the development environment in VS but not on the IIS.

Comment: What framework are you using .Net Framework or .Net Core Framework?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: by the what is your browser using Firefox/Chrome or IE?

Comment: audio element is all working on Firefox, Chrome and Edge (both VS and IIS). IE showing invalid source for the audio element (both VS and IIS).

Comment: I am tried it with Chrome and Edge. But if it works on your IIS then it looks like there is an issue with my IIS. Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the mime type in iis.IIS won’t serve .ogg files until you tell it about the type. add below code in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

you could also use iis manager to add the mime type:

1)open iis manager.

2)select your site.

3)double click on the mime type feature from the middle pane.

[image]

4)click on the add from the action pane

[image]

5)add file extension and mime-type as shown below:

[image]

6)click ok and restart the site and browse it.

Note: Make sure the file is available in the site folder. iusr and iis_iusrs have full permission to access the site folder.